# A question on tangent inverse

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

State what happens to $\frac{tan^{-1}\frac{a}{2}}{tan^{-1}a}$ when $a$ is small and very large.

I know that when $a$ is small the fraction evaluates to something close to $\frac{1}{2}$ and when $a$ is large it is close to 1.

How can I justify my answers? Any result from Calculus that I can quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know Taylor series, it is quite simple since

- close to $x=0$ $$\tan ^{-1}(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^5\right)$$
- for large values of $x$ $$\tan ^{-1}(x)=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{3 x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$

Apply twice and perform the long division.

You would even get more than the limit itself.